# VBA - SumIf with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set multiple criteria for a SumIf statement in VBA. This is what I'm using right now with only one criterion to set the value of a variable called Count_1.

```
Count_1 = Application.SumIf(Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("G84:G" & LastRow))
```

I need to add another criterion. In addition to the value in column K needing to begin with "B", the value in column L also needs to be 80.

I know this can be done using SumIfs in an Excel formula, but I need it to be in VBA.

Comment: sumifs should help

Comment: SUMIFS exists in vba, under `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Sumifs()`

Comment: I tried using this, and it's not working.

`Count_1 = Application.SumIfs(Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), "80", Range("G84:G" & LastRow))`

Comment: Try it without the quotes: `80` instead of `"80"`

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Wait, what error are you getting?  You did not say you got an error.

Comment: Sorry. I mentioned the error in another reply. I'm getting the run-time error '13.'

Comment: Are there errors (#N/A, #Value,...) in column L?

Comment: There are no errors in column L. The only values there are "80."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
Application.Sumifs(SumRange, CriteriaRange1, Criteria1, CriteriaRange2, Criteria2,...)
```

Comment: I tried that, and it's not working. I get a type mismatch error.
`Count_1 = Application.SumIfs(Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), "80", Range("G84:G" & LastRow))`

Comment: Did you dimension `B_gold` as a number (`Integer`, `Long`, `LongLong`, `Single` or `Double`)? What are the value of `LastRow`? Be sure you don't have `LastRow` as `Integer` if your sheet is too big (more then 32 000 rows). You don't seem to have errors on the formula _per se_.

Comment: Sorry, you have an error: If you use sumifs change the criteria fields by the criteria range fields on the formula... Didn't notice that on your first comment...

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `Range -> Range -> Criteria -> Range -> Criteria ->... `

Comment: I tried this, and I get the same error: `Count_1 = Application.SumIfs(Range("G84:G" & LastRow), Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), "80", Range("G84:G" & LastRow))`

Comment: @Robby remove the Colum G reference from the end: `Count_1 = Application.SumIfs(Range("G84:G" & LastRow), Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), "80")`

Comment: I think the reason why I had that there is because that's what made it count only the rows with something in column G. If I take that part out, it sort of works, but if column A is blank, it only counts what's on row 84.